# jsoup query multiple selector

Tags: jsoup

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <h1>
        <a>1</a>
    </h1>
    <h2>
        <a>2<a>
    </h2>
    <h3>
        <a>3</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to select all anchors than
div > h1 > a, div > h2 > a, div > h3 > a.
I'm looking for something like div > (h1,h2,h3) > a

Thanks,
Trung

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this:

```
div.select("h1,h2,h3").select("a");
```

alternatively, if you just need the anchors inside of the div:

```
div.select("a");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select h1,h2,h3 elements using **select("h1,h2,h3")**

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can use something like this

consider div is object of Element you get by doing this

```
Element div = document.select("div").first();
Elements anchors = div.select("a");
for(Element e: anchors)
{
  System.out.println("Anchor Text "+e.text()+" HREF VALUE = "+e.attr("href"));
}
```

This will print all anchors in your div with text they contains and the value of HREF

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class testXML {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File input = new File("D:\\test.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
    Elements divTag = doc.select("div");
    for(Element value: divTag){
        System.out.println(value.text());
    }

    Elements divTagH = doc.select("div").select("h1,h2,h3");
    for(Element value: divTagH){
        System.out.println(value.text());
    }
}
```

}

**Output:**

1 2 3
1
2
3